# Starting tasks in a dynamic way

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a `List<someObject>`
and an extention method to `someObject` called `Process`.

Consider the following

```
private void processList(List<someObject> list)
{
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{
    foreach(var instance in list)
    {
        instance.Process();
    }});
}
```

but I wanted multiple `Task`s to work on the same list, to avoid locking I cloned the list and divided it into 2 lists, then started 2 separate `Task`s to process, the speed has almost doubled.

I was wondering if there are built in things in .NET that could help me achieve such things in a dynamic way and with cleaner syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use TPL's [Parallel.Foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
var list = new List<SomeClass>();
Parallel.ForEach(list, instance =>
{
    instance.Process();
});
```

Comment: But what decides the number of threads? suppose i wanted to limit them to 4

Comment: @user1492051 you can pass `ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };` to foreach method.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Parallel.ForEach method blocks the invoking thread until all elements are processed.